# Gradle, linux and hello word on java return java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I have instaled `Gradle`, `JVM` and `Ubuntu`.

```
$ gradle -v
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.5
------------------------------------------------------------
Build time:   2017-04-10 13:37:25 UTC

Groovy:       2.4.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          9-ea (Oracle Corporation 9-ea+162)
OS:           Linux 4.10.0-21-generic amd64
```

And I have `java` project on `intellij`.
[image]

My `Gradle` config:

```
apply plugin:'java'
```

When I run `gradle build`:

```
$ gradle build 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
```

In what there can be an error?

Comment: Are you sure Gradle (or your version of Gradle) supports Java 9? Is it also failing when you use Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

It helped me:

```
export JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS='--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED'
```

Just execute in the terminal.